# How do I add brackets to the beginning of every line?

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to add `('` to the front of every line.

I tried

```
Find what: ^
Replace with: ('
```

and bracket did not show up.

How can I add it to the beginning of each line?

Answer (score 15):

#### I am trying to add `('` to the front of every line

`(` is a special character, you need to escape it with `\`

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^`
- Set "Replace with" to `\('`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing ultricies varius egestas.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing ultricies varius egestas.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing ultricies varius egestas.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing ultricies varius egestas.
```

**After**:

```
('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing ultricies varius egestas.
('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing ultricies varius egestas.
('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing ultricies varius egestas.
('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing ultricies varius egestas.
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Regular expressions: the cause of and solution to all of programming's problems. +1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Agreed. I get lots of rep answering Notepad++ reg exp questions ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, along with another post on similar, I was able to do what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to using Find/Replace could be to use a Macro:

1. Record a macro of you hitting <kbd>Home</kbd> twice, inserting your characters and then moving your cursor down to the next line (with your down arrow key).
2. Run that macro "until the end of file".

[image]

Example of how to use macros in Notepad++:

[image]

[Animation source/more info](http://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2013/10/27/notepad-macros-a-basic-example/)

Comment: Hmm. Adding `('` to the start of every line is not the same as joining all the lines up and separating them with `','`, with no `(` anywhere after you are finished. Are you answering some other question?

Comment: @DavidPostill The "example usage" animation is to show how to use macros in Notepad++, not how to solve this exact issue (that's what the rest of the answer is for). I made a couple changes to help clarify. ;)

Answer (score 0):

*Just informational (RegEx replace is the best in this situation)...*

There is [Column Mode Editing](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html) in Notepad++, so you can:

- Go to file begin <kbd>Ctrl+Home</kbd>.
- Mark to file end <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+End</kbd>.
- Mark to line begin in column mode<kbd>Shift+Alt+Home</kbd>.
- Type `('`.

Column Mode is more useful with Column Editor when you are inserting numbers.